# Changing Schema Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have created a table in a  schema called sample1 and now i want to change the schema name of the table. I tried doing it by

alter schema sample2 transfer sample1.table1

But it gives me an error.

How do I change the schema name from sample1 to sample2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
sp_changeobjectowner '[sample1].[transfer]', 'sample2'
go
```

I'm basing this on the comment you made to the other answer that you already had sample2 created.

Comment: I have a table called table1 in schema1 now I want to move the table1 into schema2. How do I change it

Comment: @Sam - Did you try the above? If it didn't work, can you provide further details?

Comment: I am getting the following error:Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_changeobjectowner, Line 21
User does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: This is what I tried sp_changeobjectowner '[sample1].[table1]', 'sample2' go

Answer (score 1):

start with `CREATE SCHEMA sample2` and then run the same command.

Comment: I don't want to create a new schema. I already have schema called sample2 to which I want to move the table.